# Google Analytics - multiple custom dimension discrepancies in report

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, custom-dimensions

Using GTM I am capturing a Custom Dimension value from the website using the Custom HTML tag.

On 8th Aug I set a GTM version live on the website , which removed white spaces from between the Custom Dimension Values.
On 13th Sept I updated a new version which doesn't remove the white spaces in the Custom Dimension Values.

When I check the GA Customization reports from Sep 14 -Sep 24 , noticed that the Custom Dimension value had 2 values - one with space and the other without space).

I am not sure how this issue is occuring , any input or guidance will be appreciated to understand this issue.
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhNqj.png)

Comment: What is the scope of the custom dimension? Hit, session or user?

Comment: the scope of the custom dimension is session